# div push down at center it right away

Tags: html, css

How do i push my content down once i do (ctrl + mouse scroll) to zoom in , and the content center it self right away.

So i have #div left #div right both beside each other, and once it zooms, #div left will push down #div right ,and #div right will center it self right away.

Here is my jsfiddle sorry please copy and paste http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/bBpEm/

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
    &nbsp;<br />
    hi
</div>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="right">right</div>    
    <div id="left">left</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    outline: red 1px solid 
}

#right { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}

#left { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
}

#outer {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Sample website** 
Try look at the home-section https://coderwall.com/welcome

As you can see once my div got pushed down the # right div wont move to center.
and also i need to center it once it is pushed down.

How do i do this, i really need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying your `div`s as `inline-block`.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBpEm/1/)

This comes with some caveats. `inline-block` elements will have whitespace surrounding them, and there are fixes for that. My preferred method is to add `margin-right: -0.36em;` to the `inline-block` elements. There are other fixes you can look up too.

Basic structure is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">&nbsp;<br />hi</div>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="right">right</div>    
    <div id="left">left</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { outline: red 1px solid }
#outer {
    text-align: center;
}
#right { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
#left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:grey;
}
```